# Scrollable Backgroundview for UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

```
UIImageView *tblBG = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
tblBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"evt_det_bg.png"]];    
self.tableView.backgroundView=tblBG;
```

I want this background view will be scrollable.Now its positioned in same place.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"evt_det_bg.png"]];
```