# Background image scroll issue with two cellview in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"evt_det_bg.png"]]autorelease];
```

I want this background view will be scrollable.

I tried the above code.But the background applied each row.I am using two cellview for the tableView.How can i achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862762/scrollable-backgroundview-for-uitableviewcontroller

Comment: I think he already tried but with no success

Comment: Yes you are correct vodkhang.The problem is 320X460 dimension background image applied each cell.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/03/how-to-add-a-nice-background-image-to-your-grouped-table-view/

Comment: Similar Question... the answer helped me too:   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813846/add-background-image-to-uitableviewcontroller-in-navigation-based-app